# Excel formula to VBA function

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I need help to create a VBA function that does the same thing as this excel formula =AVERAGEIF(A2:A13,"<="&E2,B2:B13)

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), glad to see a new member! Please check [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and make your question a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: What have you tried? This shouldn't be too difficult to have a first stab at.  Are the ranges always going to be fixed though? Or are they arguments you pass to your user defined function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [worksheetfunction.averageif method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-averageif-method-excel) might be your answer.

For example:

```
WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(Range("A2:A13"),"<="&Range("E2"),Range("B2:B13"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use like this,

[WorksheetFunction Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-averageif-method-excel)

```
Sub average()
MsgBox (WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(Worksheets(1).Range("A2:A13"), "<=" & Worksheets(1).Range("E1").Value, Worksheets(1).Range("B2:B13")))

'or like this to put in the range.

Worksheets(1).Range("F1").Formula = "=AVERAGEIF(A2:A13," >= "&E1,B2:B13)"
End Sub
```